Energy exchange between particle species in gravitational systems
Consider a gravitational system consisting of two different particle species.
Particle 1 only interacts gravitationally. Particle 2 interacts gravitationally and via some short-range force such that it can be modelled as a fluid.
Consider the limit where the total number of particles goes to infinity, while the total mass of the system remains fixed, such that the mass of each individual particle goes to zero. (I.e. we have a smooth density field). In this case, the effect of gravitational 2-body interactions should be negligable.
Initially, the system is not in equilibrium.
In this scenario, is the total energy of each species individually conserved or is energy-exchange between the species possible? If so, what is the physical mechanism behind this energy exchange?

Not sure I understand. If there is a fluid, isn't that saying the effect of 2 body interactions is not negligible? I assume you mean that particles are small enough to treat as a fluid, not massless like photons.

@mmesser314 thanks! I mean the effect of gravitational 2-body interactions between particles from species 1 and species 2. Obviously 2-body interactions between particles of species 2 will not be negligable.

If the earth was made of a single rock of species 1, a species 2 grain of dust would orbit it. The orbit would be the same if the earth was made of separate species 1 particles. Either way, 2 body gravitational interactions are important.

Yes, energy exchange is possible through the collective gravity of the particles.
A trivial example would be to start with a gravitationally bound "subcloud" of one species that is moving within a much larger cloud of the other species. The subcloud will be slowed by dynamical friction, losing energy while heating the particles of the larger cloud.
The idea of this example is that even if you make each particle have negligible mass, you can always still make massive gravitationally bound "quasiparticles" that undergo their own 2-body energy exchange.
